# Install other desktop managers

Tags: gnome, mate

Now I want to change back to Ubuntu but I still do not like the unity desktop, so I was wondering if there are any problems in installing and using Gnome 3 or Mate as a Desktop manager with Ubuntu.

Do I lose any of the functionality? Is there any software that depends on Unity to work?

Comment: If you want Gnome 3 to be installed by default, then look at [Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org/faq/).

Comment: I use Gnome 3.8 with no issue and like it very much. I also like Mate and Cinnamon and have tried both with no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no lose of any functionality, you can easily upgrade and run gnome 3 as a desktop manager.

Comment: And what about mate?

Comment: yes you can also upgrade to mate or any other linux desktop environment without any issue.